# What is the key difference between using and not using times argument in R rep() command?

Tags: r

```
v <-c(rep('hello',5),('world',5))
```

output: [1] "mow"   "mow"   "mow"   "mow"   "mow"   "unmow" "unmow" "unmow" "unmow" "unmow"

```
v <-c(rep('hello',times=5),('world', times=5))
```

output: [1] "mow"   "mow"   "mow"   "mow"   "mow"   "unmow" "unmow" "unmow" "unmow" "unmow"

I have run the above mentioned code, one each at a time, and both produced the same output. What is the use of 'times=5' argument in the second code if the first code produced the same output just by mentioning a simple numerical?

Comment: Try `rep` with a vector to see how it works.

Comment: In case you wonder why `rep("hello",5)` and `rep("hello,times=5)` produces the same output: You can specify arguments of functions by position, name, or partial name. Arguments are matched first by exact name, then by prefix, and finally by position. [See](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html)

Comment: It produced the same output on vectors too both numerical and character .

Answer (score 0):

`times` is the default second argument of the `rep()` function, so if you do not specify `times` in the second argument it's still being used anyway.

Try...

```
rep(c("hello", "world"), times = 5)
rep(c("hello", "world"), 5)
rep(c("hello", "world"), each = 5)
```

The first two should give you the same output, with alternating words. The third lists each word 5 times before listing the second word.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't write `times=`, R understands by the position in your list of parameters that what you mean by 5 is `times = 5`